# Page Cannot Be deleted because of specific renderings

Tags: presentation, content-management

A very specific scenario where the components on a page are causing exception while trying to delete the page.

To reproduce :

1. Two components are needed

   - A simple component which uses a datasource (say an article ).
   - A Component with Parameter template with following field ( treelist ex) In my case it is a component where user could select the pages to highlight without requiring datasource.
2. Add two article components on the page associate them with datasource.
3. Add the Component with the rendering parameter template and select few pages from content tree. Save everything.
4. Now Go to the content editor and try deleting the page.
5. Select Remove Links

   Result :

   > Job started: RemoveLinks|Sitecore.Exceptions.EditingNotAllowedException: Item '/sitecore/templates/Feature/News/ParametersTemplate_NewsListingC28/__Standard Values' is not in editing mode.

### Resolution

In order to delete the page we now need to manually deselect items from the treelist selection from the component.

Also replicates on Sitecore Version 9.0

Cannot Understand the reason for this specific error. Any help much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that's a question for Sitecore Support